# How to restrict users to upload certain type of file?

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts2

I need to restrict users to upload certain type of files, how should I do that? I know that I can receive  the file and check the ContentType variable but I need to change the way their browser looks for files.

Lets say the required file type is csv, when they click on upload and the window will be opened to look for files in their file system, they should only be able to ***see files with csv extension***. In this way they are forced to upload CSV files as no other file is visible to be selected.

```
<s:form id="uploadCSV" method="POST" action="add"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file name="csv" label="Upload File"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: to run tests one can use this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers support "[accept](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)" attribute with the Input File control. If you are looking for all browser support, you may need to use any flash based upload plugin.

Other than that, as you said checking the ContentType is the only way of doing it.

Comment: I am using <s:file> not input

Comment: That should not be a problem, you can also use normal HTML input file tag with the same name as that of the Bean property. Struts will take care of the binding.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 standard specifies an [`accept` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-input-accept) for input elements. It allows you to specify the MIME type and the extension and the standard recommends specifying both, so your code should look like this:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv,text/csv"></input>
```

HTML4 [does not allow specifying extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-accept), so you can only use the MIME type:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/csv"></input>
```

Comment: html5 is not supported by all browsers is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Yes, using HTML4. But it seems all the major browsers support the HTML5 accept attribute: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html Other than that, you could do some client-side JS validation that checks the extension, but that does not restrict the files available in the input dialog.